# Question on std::system() and exec usage in this scenario

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a question on the usage of std::system or exec or maybe even fork.

The scenario is based on my usage and does not require to be portable(the environment is in Linux)

The scenario as such:

```
(1) I have an application A, already running which needs to startup another application B
(2) B would starting running and spawn multiple thread, of which one of them is a TCP comms thread which is running it as server
(3) After B startup is completed, A would need to establish TCP connection to B with A being the client and B being the server
(4) A would then issue commands to B
```

Code Snippets:

```
int main()
{
    tcpClient client;
    std::cout << "starting A TCP connection with B " << std::endl;
    client.init("x.x.x.x", xxx);             

    std::cout << "Starting B " << std::endl;
    std::system("./B");    // start B application

    sleep(5);     // let it sleep

    /// to prove that communication is working
    std::cout << "Sending Test Message " << std::endl;
    std::string command = "x";
    client.send(command.c_str(),1);

    //...... rest of code run
}
```

The program either blocks on B threads (always show B threads running) or show A program runnnig.

IS this the right way to use std::system since I have thought it to be aynschronous(returning control to A after B finish setup ) or does it mean that after B has finished running everything and exit?

Is there someways for B to message A after its setup is completed(though not finished running everything) ?

REgarsd

Comment: Why the C tag? That code is not C.

Comment: The behaviour of `system()` is implementation-defined.   As such, the standard provides no guarantee about whether it blocks (e.g. waits for a child process to complete) or not.   Practically, most implementations block.  If you want to launch/spawn an asynchronous program, you need to use approaches specific to the target platform (e.g. `fork()` and `exec()` or similar functions under unix,  `CreateProcess()` with the windows API, etc).   Depending on needs you might find a third-party library that handles such system-specific features for you.

Comment: However, it should work if you use `system()` in a separate thread. This way you can proceed in your main thread while the other thread is blocking in `system()`. -- Once, I tried to `fork()`/`exec()` to run a command line tool in a GUI wrapper where console output of the command line tool should be viewed in the GUI. While this was easy to achieve in Linux, it caused me headache in Windows. Though, the applications were running concurrently no console output appeared in the GUI until the other process was finished. I had to do the spawn of the cmd. line tool in a separate thread to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

In your (Linux, or more generally POSIX) context, the manpage for `system(3)` probably says something like this (copied from the Arch Linux manpages; other POSIX systems have different wording):

> The system() library function uses fork(2) to create a child process that executes the shell command specified in command using execl(3) as follows:
> execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *) NULL);
> system() returns after the command has been completed.

As @ScheffsCat points out -- @Peter as well -- there's a lot of latitude for implementations. In any case `system(3)` returns after the command completes: if your program *B* doesn't exit, it doesn't complete either. Your description says *B* acts as a server, so that's probably the case.

On a Linux system you can exploit the fact that `system(3)` goes via a shell, and background the command:

```
std::system("./B &");
```

But it **is** better to use `fork(2)/exec(2)` if you're doing multi-process work, since `system(3)` has all that wriggle room.

(And only now that I've written all this **C**-based answer, do I read the C++ `std::system()` documentation that adds even more wriggle room -- it **probably** calls `system(3)` in your implementation, but does not need to.)

Comment: @Adriaan_de_Groot: ok thanks ...i have used fork instead.. but how do you end/terminate program B if you need to end A